# How to make argumentcompleter work in a PowerShell dynamic parameter?

Tags: powershell, dynamic, parameters

There are many examples on the internet showing how to write a basic dynamic parameter, I've seen only one example of how to have multiple dynamic parameters in one function, but I haven't seen any examples of how to implement argument completer in a dynamic parameter.

Here's an example of a basic dynamic parameter I have:

```
Param(
    [Parameter( Position = 0, Mandatory = $True, HelpMessage = 'Choose a VM host for the VM(s).' )]
    [ValidateScript( {
        If ($null -eq $global:DefaultVIServer) {
            Write-Host -BackgroundColor Yellow -ForegroundColor Red -Object 'Connect to vCenter!'
            Break
        }
        Else {
            If ($PSItem -in ((Get-VMHost).Name)) {
                $True
            }
            Else {
                Throw "Accepted values: $(((Get-VMHost).Name) -join ', ')"
            }
        }
    } )]
    [ArgumentCompleter( {
        Param ($Cmd, $Param, $ParamComplete)
        [Array]$ValidValues = (Get-VMHost | Sort-Object CpuUsageMhz).Name
        $ValidValues -like "$ParamComplete*"
    } )]
    [String]$VMHost
)

DynamicParam {
    ## Dynamic DataStore.
    $DynamicDataStore = 'DataStore'

    $Attributes = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
    $Attributes.Position = 1
    $Attributes.Mandatory = $True
    $AttributeCollection = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]'
    $AttributeCollection.Add($Attributes)

    $HostDataStores = (Get-VMHost -Name $VMHost | Get-Datastore | Sort-Object FreeSpaceGB -Descending).Name

    $ValidateSetAttribute = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute($HostDataStores)
    $AttributeCollection.Add($ValidateSetAttribute)

    $DynamicParamater = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($DynamicDataStore, [String], $AttributeCollection)

    $DynamicParameterDictionary = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary
    $DynamicParameterDictionary.Add($DynamicDataStore, $DynamicParamater)

    Return $DynamicParameterDictionary
}

Begin {
    # Make the dynamic parameter available for the auto-complete.
    $DataStore = $PSBoundParameters[$DynamicDataStore]
}
```

The problem with this implementation is that as you can see, I'm trying to list datastores with the most amount of space first, but the validateset array doesn't care about my ordering and orders the values alphabetically (argument tab completion works here).

So I thought of using argumentcompleter, which does work in a way I want in a regular parameter (see VMHost parameter in the first example), but looks like I can't get it to work in a dynamic parameter and I'm hoping someone else has solved this or can guide me in the right direction.

What I've tried so far:

```
DynamicParam {
    ## Dynamic DataStore.
    $DynamicDataStore = 'DataStore'

    $Attributes = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
    $Attributes.Position = 1
    $Attributes.Mandatory = $True
    $AttributeCollection = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]'
    $AttributeCollection.Add($Attributes)

    $ValidateScriptAttribute = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.ValidateScriptAttribute({
        If ($PSItem -in (Get-VMHost -Name $VMHost | Get-Datastore).Name) {
            $True
        }
        Else {
            Throw "Accepted values: $(((Get-VMHost -Name $VMHost | Get-Datastore).Name) -join ', ')"
        }
    })

    $DynamicArgumentCompleter = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.ArgumentCompleterAttribute({
        Param ($Cmd, $Param, $ParamComplete)
        [Array]$ValidValues = (Get-VMHost -Name $VMHost | Get-Datastore | Sort-Object FreeSpaceGB -Descending).Name
        $ValidValues -like "$ParamComplete*"
    })

    $AttributeCollection.Add($ValidateScriptAttribute)
    $AttributeCollection.Add($DyamicArgumentCompleter)

    $DynamicParamater = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($DynamicDataStore, [String], $AttributeCollection)

    $DynamicParameterDictionary = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary
    $DynamicParameterDictionary.Add($DynamicDataStore, $DynamicParamater)

    Return $DynamicParameterDictionary
}
```

This seemed like a logical way to do it.

The ValidateScriptBlock part works. I enter an incorrect value and get an error saying: "Accepted values: list of comma-delimited values", but the argumentcompleter doesn't do anything.

What I'm expecting it to do is show me accepted values when I press tab after -DataStore parameter, but there's no tab completion at all, not alphabetically ordered, or anything.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest and robust way to do it is with [`Register-ArgumentCompleter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/register-argumentcompleter?view=powershell-7.3), I don't have access to your completion set but using `Get-Process` as the completion source and a dynamic param here is how the implementation looks like:

```bash
function Test-DynamicParam {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName = 'foo')]
        $foo
    )

    DynamicParam {
        if($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'foo') {
            $paramDictionary = [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary]::new()
            $attributes = [Parameter[]] [Parameter]@{
                Position  = 1
                Mandatory = $true
            }
            $runtimeParam = [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter]::new('bar', [string], $attributes)
            $paramDictionary.Add('bar', $runtimeParam)
            $paramDictionary
        }
    }
}

$params = @{
    CommandName   = 'Test-DynamicParam'
    ParameterName = 'bar'
    ScriptBlock   = {
        param(
            $commandName,
            $parameterName,
            $wordToComplete,
            $commandAst,
            $fakeBoundParameters
        )

        (Get-Process).ProcessName | Sort-Object -Unique |
            Where-Object { $_ -like "*$wordToComplete*" }
    }
}
Register-ArgumentCompleter @params
```

Demo:

[image: demo]

Comment: ok, at first I added the $params scriptblock and Register-ArgumentCompleter cmdlet to Begin block inside the function, but that didn't work, even copy-paste of your code. So I moved them out of the function and I got your example working, but that seems to introduce another issue, I need the value of in your case foo and when the argumentcompleter is out of the function, it has no way of knowing what the value of foo is.